# How to achieve a slightly transparent text with border in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have white, slightly transparent text with a black border, so I started by setting the

```
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
```

for the text. Here's the result:
[image]

Then I added

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
```

, but I got what's in the picture below, so I abandoned this idea

[image]

I decided that instead of 'text-stroke,' I would add

```
text-shadow:
        1px 1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000;
```

but once again, it didn't work out

[image]

**How can I achieve the effect from the first picture but with a black border that won't be distorted by the font?**

I am using a font: Montserrat

Comment: I've done this by overlapping two divs with the same text -  The one in "back" or lower `z-index` has the `stroke` and just use the `opacity` property on the "back" div ...

Comment: @Zak Is it possible for you to send me your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1amso35h/  I created this as an example.

Comment: Use an SVG? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ExMYZZP?editors=1100